Is there a way to grant SELECT access to a DB2 table through a stored procedure alone
We have a use case where we are storing some credentials in encrypted form within our warehouse. The decryption paraphrase is loaded at runtime through k8s secret, passed on to a stored procedure, which in turn checks a few other criteria to return the credentials. This is at a POC phase where a handful of users have SELECT access to the underlying table as well EXECUTE access on the stored procedure. However, we are trying to see if there is a way to make Stored Procedure the only entry point - that is users will not have access to the underlying table and they can only access the credentials through the stored procedure. That way, if someone looks at the source code of the SP and understands the checks in place, they still won't be able to access the content in the table.

Typical pattern is that the security config would revoke all access to that table, except to the owner of the sproc, users or roles with execute right on the sproc would indirectly access the table only if the sproc runs.
